# It takes my computer a long time to establish connections with websites

Tags: networking, internet, connection

I recently moved to a new house, got a new computer, and upgraded from Win7 to Win8. When I go on a webpage, the browser goes into the white loading screen for about 5-10 seconds, then everything loads almost instantly. It doesn't matter if I go on a media-heavy webpage or a simple webpage, they all take the same time. For videos, it takes 5-10 seconds to open the webpage, but I can watch 1080 videos without any lag.

My connection speed is 25Mb up, 1Mb down. Speedtest.net: http://www.speedtest.net/result/3273746569.png

This problem only occurs on my desktop, which is connected to the router using an ethernet cable. This problem occurs in both my browsers: Chrome and Firefox. My PHP scripts also take a long time to fetch pages, so it isn't my browser's issue. I tried pinging several websites. Half the websites take about 10-50ms, and the other half timed out.

I'm thinking there's an issue with my computer when it initially establishes a connection with a website. How do I find the issue?

Comment: Going to have to do some more trouble shooting on your end to narrow this down. First, I would see if other computers on your network have the same issue. Try to isolate where the problem is and work from there.

Comment: Oh right, I forgot to mention that this only occurs on a desktop connected to the router using a Cat6 wire. All of my other devices work fine.

Comment: I recently switched ISPs and one of the boxes in our house was behaving poorly.  Poked around and discovered that at some point I had set the nameserver address for that box to something other than the ISP's default (which was being flaky off and on).  Switched it back to default and things were much better.  (Note that you override name servers on a connection basis, meaning that a wired connection may work and a WiFi connection fail, or vice-versa.)

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like a nameserver issue. Think about what happens when you request a domain:

1) You request a port at a domain (some website)

2) It checks it DNS cache for the correct address.

3) If not found it queries the DNS server defined in your interfaces. ( I would assume this is your problem here )

4) DNS server repsonds with correct IP and you query the site.

I would bet your DNS server is set to localhost, and its taking a long time to find an authoritative server.

Try setting your DNS server to 8.8.8.8 (Googles DNS) and you should find your answer.

Comment: Oddly enough, I switched my DNS server from Google's server to Dyn's server and my connection became a bit faster (I was using Google's before). However, there's still a 2-5 second delay about half the time.

Comment: Find your ISPs DNS servers and use those instead. It will be a little better

Answer (score 1):

I found that (with Firefox) going to settings - advanced - network, setting it to no proxy did the trick.  FAST TO FIND AND LOAD PAGES NOW.